# Futures in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am having a hard time understanding the point of this example:

```
(let [result (future (println "this prints once")
                 (+ 1 1))]
   (println "deref: " (deref result))
   (println "@: " @result))
```

[The author explains:](http://www.braveclojure.com/concurrency/)

> Notice that the string "this prints once" indeed prints only once, even though you dereference the future twice. This shows that the future’s body ran only once and the result, 2, got cached.

I don't get it; the string will print once even without dereferencing the future. What is this example supposed to teach?

Comment: Most likely nothing more than a simple fact that the future is evaluated only once and multiple dereference operations don't trigger re-execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree this is subtle.  The point of this is to show that `future` is a one-time evaluation.  Sure, the `println` side effect occurs whether you deref "result" or not.  In fact, the side effect occurs without later deref-ing "result" as you've noted.  Merely binding "result" causes the `println` side effect to occur.

More importantly, the idea here is that deref-ing "result" twice explicitly does *not* cause it to be evaluated (or bound) twice.  In other words, it does not cause the `println` side effect twice.  You get the cached value of 2 both times you `deref` it.

One might expect deref-ing it twice would cause it to be bound twice, and therefore execute the `println` twice.  But this is not the case.  Instead, you get the cached, deref-ed value just once.  The point here is more that the side effect occurs upon binding, not upon deref-ing, and that deref-ing twice does not incur a second binding.

Answer (score 2):

The `future` executes the enclosed code in a separate thread and starts the execution immediately so it will run the code even if you don't reference the result value.

I guess the author wanted to show that the `future` body won't be reexecuted when you dereference it more than once.